# How to detect ENTER key press on an input field before the form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Please check the following code:

https://codepen.io/tkpop777/pen/vYYVBOe

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" value="text field 1" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" value="text field 2" id="textfield2" />  
  <br />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
document.querySelector('#textfield2').onkeyup = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('enter key')
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('form submitted');
}
```

If you are on the second input field and hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key you will receive the "form submitted" alert and never the "enter key" alert. Moving the input field out of the form tags gives you the "enter key" alert. How can I receive that alert even when that field is within the form tags. Basically it should fire first before the form submitted alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `onkeydown` instead of `onkeyup`

```
document.querySelector('#textfield2').onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('enter key')
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('form submitted');
}
```

Note: I also removed `e.preventDefault()` from the `onkeydown` event so that the form is actually submitted afterwards.

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/tkpop777/pen/vYYVBOe

Answer (score 0):

Your `onsubmit` event takes precedence because you are not listening on for a `keydown` event but for a `keyup`.

This should do what you need:

```
document.querySelector('#textfield2').onkeydown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('enter key')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't prevent your button from submitting the form, which is why this is happening. By default when you hit enter, the button in your form is triggered and the form gets submitted.

just add this

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```